# calculate the backchain RMSD between two pdb files by pymol in Python

Tags: python, pymol

i have two protein pdb files and want to calculate the backchain RMSD between them. As far as I know the GUI of Pymol can use align to calculate the RMSD (but I don't know if it is the backchain RMSD).I want to use the python code to use pymol to calculate the backchain RMSD. I know how to align them but don't know how to calculate the RMSD.

```
import pymol2
with pymol2.PYMOL() as pymol:
    pymol.cmd.load('foo.pdb', 'foo')
    pymol.cmd.load('bar.pdb', 'bar')
    pymol.cmd.align('foo', 'bar')
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

The backbone can be specified using a selector for the names of these, which are `N`, `CA` (Cα) and `C` (C-prime).

```
out = pymol.cmd.align('foo and name N+CA+C and polymer', 'bar and name N+CA+C and polymer')
rmsd, n_atoms, n_cyles, n_rmsd_pre, n_atom_pre, score, n_res = out
```

If you do not wish the proteins to be moved you can use `rms_cur`, which is just the rmsd.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It works well! however,i want to further learn related knowledge about pymol like this. Can you provide some web/cook book name?